# how to create drop down panel with two steps

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, dropdown

I would like to create a drop down panel that when you collapse it, it will close only half and when you expand, it will expand and show the other items as shown in below image.

I already tried to use SplitConatainer and by hide the panel manage my work but my problem is when I collapse it the other items not rearrange. please refer to below image.

button code:

```
 if (splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed)
                splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;
            else
                splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
```

Also I tried to set size of panel but it is not rendering and effecting.

would you mind help me in introducing some previous work that have ability of customization. Or help me to start create such component please?

[image]

Comment: You will have to control both Top and Height of both the Panel and the DGV below it. Or go for a SplitContainer: Let panel1 contain the buttons inside a groupbox and panel2 the DGV. Let the use do the sizing and maybe even drop the expand button..

Comment: @TaW: so you mean that I cannot use automate behavior of component to rearrange them? I mean like Flowlayout items find their new place dynamically.

Comment: Not sure. The positioning should work but the sizing didn't when I tried. But I must admit didn't try very hard.. Dock.Fill sounds pronising but I didn't get it to work. Setting up anchors is another option to test..

Comment: @TaW: Thanks for the tip, let me try.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by add a parameter to project "ExpandCollapsePanel" in GitHub.

So Just by adding a value to MaximumCollapseHeight, you can control panel.

you can get the source code from here.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Amirhatami/ExpandCollapsePanel)